# SQL Server 2008 database Publishing Wizard

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to run a database import using the Copy Database Wizard Tool from SQL Server Management Studio in SQL Server 2008.

I have connected to my database using the `sa` account and when I run the process I used the `sa` account on both the source and destination database.

All the processes are failing with

> *Event 18556, Login failed for user '{domain}\administrator'.
>
>   Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: ]*

The `SA` account should have sufficient rights to import the database and the administrator account definitely has the rights.

So, the first question is, why is the administrator account even mentioned since everything is run as `SA`?

The second question is, why is the administrators account failing to open the explicitly specified database, when that account has total control of all databases on the destination server?

Finally, what exactly is the specified database? There is data in the binary portion of "event log" that points to `Master` but no mention of the database anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting to SSMS using pass through authentication? Your wizard will run as your user I believe if so.  Connect to your database server in SSMS using the sa account and then try launching it.

Give it a valid account to the other database, sa needs access locally, the 2nd account needs access on your other SQL server.

Alternatively, make sure your domain user has access to the database in question (not the server, the db is dif.) and run it that way.

The master db is where all the sys tables reside, it's the overlord db so to say: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187837.aspx